# How to encode (hash) a big string into a 4 letter string?

Tags: python, hash

I want to build an ID for each row of a datatable based on entries in multiple columns.

How to proceed in order to convert a long string, let's say `hello2017good` into a 3 or 4 letter string that can have only letters but uppercase/lowercase both allowed ?

Comment: With 3 or 4 letter character hashes, there are good chances of collisions.

Comment: 4 letters (uppercase and lowercase) only gives you a 52  ** 4 == 7311616 possible values. Are you certain you will have fewer than 7.3 million possible entries in your database? 3 letters limits you to 140608 unique 'hashes', I'd not count on avoiding collisions.

Comment: 3 or 4 letters is too few to do what you want. Follow @selbie's line but store the whole 20-byte digest, not just bits of it. With a hash function you will start getting collisions far quicker than the number of possible values might suggest.

Comment: @BoarGules I'll consider the pros and cons, thank you for your concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a standard hash algorithm, like sha1, and use the random array of bytes returned to index into a table of a to z (and A-Z).

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.sha1(b"hello2017good")
d = h.digest()
s = ""
for i in range(0,4):
    x = d[i] % 52
    if x >= 26:
        s += chr(ord('A') + x - 26)
    else:
        s += chr(ord('a') + x)
print(s)
```

Comment: Taking the first 4 characters of a 40-character hex digest is a *bad idea*. You are preserving only 10% of the codespace (4 hex digits, 2 bytes), So the shortened digest has only 64k different possible values, and you will start getting collisions far sooner than that.

Comment: I'm giving the OP exactly what he asked for.  He never said he had a requirement to be cryptographically secure.

Comment: Who said anything about cryptographic security? 4 letters is way too small a valeu set to avoid collisions.